# Error with rpart function in R: Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) : duplicated name 'X.' in data frame using '.'

Tags: r, text-classification, rpart

I was running some classification models for twitter sentiment analysis and I came across this error when using the rpart function:

`Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) :  duplicated name 'X.' in data frame using '.'`

Hope someone could help me solve it.

Here are the entire codes that I have used so far (apart from loading in the libraries):

```
setwd("D:/ProjectTwitterTrial")
ustweets <- read.csv('tweets.csv', header = T)
str(ustweets)

set.seed(123) 
tweets <- ustweets[sample(nrow(ustweets)),]
tweets <- tweets %>% 
  select(airline_sentiment, negativereason, airline, text, tweet_location)

tweets %>% distinct() # Keep only unique/distinct rows from the data frame

tweets$language = textcat(tweets$text)
tweets = subset(tweets, language =='english')

datadtm = DocumentTermMatrix(corpus)
datadtm = removeSparseTerms(datadtm, 0.999)

dataset <- as.data.frame(as.matrix(datadtm))
colnames(dataset) <- make.names(colnames(dataset))
dataset$airline_sentiment <- tweets$airline_sentiment
str(dataset$airline_sentiment)

dataset$airline_sentiment <- as.factor(dataset$airline_sentiment)

set.seed(222)
split = sample(2,nrow(dataset),prob = c(0.8,0.2),replace = TRUE)
train_set = dataset[split == 1,]
test_set = dataset[split == 2,]
train_set[4:6,57:59]
test_set[4:6,57:59]

rf_classifier = randomForest(airline_sentiment ~., data=train_set, ntree = 20)
```

Comment: data.frame `train_set` appears to have more than one column named "`X.`"... `colnames(train_data)` to inspect...

Comment: @br00t I see. I guess I'll remove the duplicated columns using the subset() function. Thanks!